# What is the meaning of "barnet front"?

Tags: meaning, colloquialisms

In an article in yesterday's *European*, on the US election, Kevin O'Sullivan, writing of Hillary Clinton says,

*In fairness, on the **barnet front** she's head and shoulders above her rival. But then, again, who isn't?*

The text had previously just been referring to her lack of sartorial elegance, and then this mention. What is the ***barnet front***?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

*Barnet* is Cockney rhyming slang: *Barnet Fair* → *hair.*

*On the X front* is a set phrase relating to the particular situation of X:

> 2.3 A particular situation or sphere of operation:
>   *‘there was some good news on the jobs front’
>
>   ‘On the political front, the situation has been marked by total paralysis.’*
>
> [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/front)

Thus: "In the particular matter of coiffure, she's in a far better position than her rival."

Comment: Thanks Andrew. I had forgotten about *the state of her barnet* - it's decades since I heard that.

Comment: And the phrase originally referred to a 525 year old horse and cattle fair...https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barnet_Fair

Comment: Wonder what American readers made of that!